# CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync hangs, stalls, never returns

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ilogger

I have a working Blazor app that reads and writes to CosmosDb.  Trying to add some new functionality, which works fine locally, but bombs after deploying to Azure.  I've traced the problem to somewhere in my `CosmosDbService`.  I want to add `ILogger` into `CosmosDbService` and further trace down my problem.  However, while testing the DI, my code stalls at `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databasename)`.  No errors in the prior code.  No exceptions, no timeouts, nothing just a silent fail.  The Azure is not reporting anything.  If I roll everything back to original state, it works.  Obviously it is there somewhere, but I am not seeing it.  So my questions are 1) Why does my app now stall/hang?  2) Am I injecting ILogger correctly into my CosmosDbService?  Here is the relevant code.

```
Startup.cs
....
            services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>((s) =>
            {
                var logger = s.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CosmosDbService>>();
                return InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb"), logger).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            });
'''
        private static async Task<CosmosDbService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(IConfigurationSection configurationSection, ILogger logger)
        {
            string databaseName = configurationSection.GetSection("DatabaseName").Value;
            string containerRatings = configurationSection.GetSection("ContainerRatings").Value;
            string containerUsers = configurationSection.GetSection("ContainerUsers").Value;
            string containerLocations = configurationSection.GetSection("ContainerLocations").Value;

            string account = configurationSection.GetSection("Account").Value;
            string key = configurationSection.GetSection("Key").Value;
            CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(account, key);
            CosmosClient client = clientBuilder
                                .WithConnectionModeDirect()
                                .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.Default })
                                .Build();
            //CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerRatings, containerUsers, containerLocations);
            CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService()
            {
                ContainerRatings = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerRatings),
                ContainerRateLocationSmall = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerLocations),
                ContainerRateUser = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerUsers),
                CosmosClient = client,
                DatabaseName = databaseName
                , _logger = logger
            };

            DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerRatings, "/What");
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerUsers, "/UserName");
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerLocations, "/id");
            return cosmosDbService;
        }
...
CosmosDBService.cs
...
    public class CosmosDbService : ICosmosDbService
    {
        public CosmosClient CosmosClient { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public Container ContainerRatings { get; set; }
        public Container ContainerRateUser { get; set; }
        public Container ContainerRateLocationSmall { get; set; }

        public ILogger _logger { get; set; }
        //public CosmosDbService() { }
...
```

Thanks in advance.

--UPDATE 2020-12-06 ---

Thank you Quango.  Your questions and suggestions stimulated a new line of thinking.  I'm giving you credit for the answer.

1. I noticed that the new line in `Startup.cs` was causing the service to lazy load much later in the actual program execution:

```
                var logger = s.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CosmosDbService>>();
```

When I returned this line to its original syntax, it initialized during Startup successfully.

```
            services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

2. Getting ILogger injected into my CosmosDBService.  Doing re-RTFM on Logging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) it seemed I needed to use the Factory instead.
   So I changed the instantiation to this:

```
            LoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            //CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerR8ings, containerUsers, containerLocations);
            CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService()
            {
                ContainerR8ings = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerR8ings),
                ContainerR8User = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerUsers),
                ContainerR8LocationSmall = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerLocations),
                _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("CosmosDbService")               
            };
```

And correspondingly to the CosmosDBService by removing the explicit constructor and using the implicit one.  Then I was able to add Logger to the service.

3. Finally this enabled me to track the original bug I was hunting.

Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Just removed the Blazor tag thinking "this is a CosmosDB issue".. is this Blazor server or WASM? Where is the code running?

Comment: Blazor server.  Haven't been able to rule out Blazor as accomplice.  Deployed to Azure.

Comment: Just wanted to check you were not trying to access CosmosDB from the client (I've seen it done)

Comment: Looking at the code I'd want to log the configuration vaules that got loaded to ensure I've not got anything wrong/mistyped and verify what the code was trying to do. Secondly I'd add a `try`-`catch` section to the `InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync` to catch and log the exceptions. Also have a look at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited for suggestions on improving the configuration.

Comment: Just noticed the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` - almost certainly that's why you're not getting the error - this way around the async issue often swallows errors. I'll post a suggested alternative approach

Comment: Nope, not trying to access from Client.

Comment: Good suggestions about try catch.  See further details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen you cannot asynchronously initialize a service in the service registration process. The solution I use in these cases is not to create the service directly, but return a factory or provider service which has an `async Task<T> CreateAsync` method to do this. You register this provider as the service, then inject this provider and call `CreateAsync` in the code. Here is an example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestWebsite.Services
{
    public class CosmosDbProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ctor: values provided by DI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration"></param>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>
        public CosmosDbProvider(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
        {
            config = configuration;
            log = logger;
        }

        IConfiguration config;
        ILogger log;

        ICosmosDbService cachedService;

        public async Task<ICosmosDbService> CreateAsync()
        {
            // use a cached instance for all requests (similar to Lazy<T> but async)
            if (cachedService == null)
            {
                cachedService = await InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync();
            }
            return cachedService;
        }

        private async Task<CosmosDbService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation("InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync started");

                // I'd recommend GetValue<T> for reading single values over GetSection
                string databaseName = config.GetValue<string>("DatabaseName");
                string containerRatings = config.GetValue<string>("ContainerRatings");
                string containerUsers = config.GetValue<string>("ContainerUsers");
                string containerLocations = config.GetValue<string>("ContainerLocations");

                string account = config.GetValue<string>("Account");
                string key = config.GetValue<string>("Key");

                log.LogDebug($"databaseName: {databaseName}");
                log.LogDebug($"containerRatings: {containerRatings}");
                log.LogDebug($"containerUsers: {containerUsers}");
                log.LogDebug($"containerLocations: {containerLocations}");
                // might not want to log sensitive info..
                // log.LogDebug($"account: {account}");
                // log.LogDebug($"key: {key}");

                log.LogDebug("Creating CosmosClientBuilder");
                CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(account, key);
                
                log.LogDebug("Creating CosmosClient");
                CosmosClient client = clientBuilder
                                    .WithConnectionModeDirect()
                                    .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.Default })
                                    .Build();

                log.LogDebug("Creating CosmosDbService");
                CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService()
                {
                    ContainerRatings = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerRatings),
                    ContainerRateLocationSmall = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerLocations),
                    ContainerRateUser = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerUsers),
                    CosmosClient = client,
                    DatabaseName = databaseName,
                    _logger = log
                };

                log.LogDebug($"CreateDatabase for '{databaseName}'");
                DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
                
                log.LogDebug($"CreateContainer for '{containerRatings}'");
                await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerRatings, "/What");
                
                log.LogDebug($"CreateContainer for '{containerUsers}'");
                await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerUsers, "/UserName");

                log.LogDebug($"CreateContainer for '{containerLocations}'");
                await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerLocations, "/id");

                log.LogInformation("InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync completed");
                return cosmosDbService;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogError(e, "Failed when initializing CosmosDB");
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I changed your config code to use `GetValue<T>` - I think it's simpler, and added a bunch of logging statements. Mostly these are `LogDebug` so in production you'll need to change to debug-level (or you can change to `LogInformation` if you wish) to help diagnose the issue.

In `Startup.cs` we add:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<CosmosDbProvider>();
```

To get the CosmosDB instance you inject the provider using DI. In controllers, Razor and Blazor pages you can then make `async` calls: e.g. a sample Blazor page `Cosmos.razor`

```
@page "/cosmos"
@inject TestWebsite.Services.CosmosDbProvider cosmosProvider;

<h3>Cosmos</h3>

@if(_db !=null)
{
    <p>Your database is called @_db.DatabaseName</p>
}

@code {

    TestWebsite.Services.ICosmosDbService _db;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // create/get CosmosDbService
        _db = await cosmosProvider.CreateAsync();
    }
}
```